# Add extra column to form table on button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a HTML form part of which is within a HTML form which is generated by the below PHP code:

```
<?php $rows = array(
        array('weight' => 1000, 'cbm_min' => 0.1, 'cbm_max' => 2.3 ),
        array('weight' => 1500, 'cbm_min' => 2.31, 'cbm_max' => 3.5 ),
        array('weight' => 2000, 'cbm_min' => 3.51, 'cbm_max' => 4.6 ),
        array('weight' => 2500, 'cbm_min' => 4.61, 'cbm_max' => 5.75 ),
        array('weight' => 3000, 'cbm_min' => 5.75, 'cbm_max' => 6.9 )
); 

?>  
<form name="createtable" action="?page=createtable" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <label for=tablename>Name of Table</label>
    <input type=text name=tablename id=tablename>
      <table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th> Weight </th>
                <th> CBM Min </th>
                <th> CBM Max </th>
                <th> Min </th>
            </tr>
<?php
$i = 1; // I'll use this to increment the input text name
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  // Everything happening inside this foreach will loop for as many records/rows that are in the $rows array.
 ?>
    <tr>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['weight'] ?> </th>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['cbm_min'] ?> </th>
      <th> <?= (float) $row['cbm_max'] ?> </th>
      <th> <input type=text name="min<?= (float) $i ?>"> </th>
    </tr>
  <?php
  $i++;
}
?>
  </table>
  <input type=submit value="Create Table">
</form>
```

When the user fills in the form and submits it the contents is then used to create a mysql table.
The idea is the form would replicate what the created mysql table would look like.
This works well, however now I need to be able to add extra 'columns' to the forms table.

I.e when a user presses a button another column would appear in the forms table so the user can fill in the values and then this column would be added to the data passed onto the php function that creates the mysql table.

**Php that handles the data submitted**

```
<?php
if($page == "createtable"){
$tablename = $_POST['tablename'];
$mins = array($_POST['min1'],$_POST['min1'],$_POST['min2'],$_POST['min3'],$_POST['min4'],$_POST['min5'],$_POST['min6'],$_POST['min7'],$_POST['min8'],
        $_POST['min9'],$_POST['min10'],$_POST['min11'],$_POST['min12'],$_POST['min13'],$_POST['min14'],$_POST['min15'],$_POST['min16'],$_POST['min17'],$_POST['min18'],
        $_POST['min19'],$_POST['min20'],$_POST['min21'],$_POST['min22'],$_POST['min23'],$_POST['min24'],$_POST['min25'],$_POST['min26'],$_POST['min27'],$_POST['min28'],
        $_POST['min29'],$_POST['min30']);    
$log->createTable($tablename, $mins);
}
?>
```

**function used to create mysql**
I know this does not protect the mysql my injection attacks etc I mearly created it for testing etc and will need to redo it for the new changes anyway

```
function createTable($tablename, $mins){
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","****");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $tableCreate = "CREATE TABLE rates_{$tablename} (
                                              Weight int(11),
                                              CBMMin double,
                                              CBMMax double,
                                              Min double
                                              ) 
        ";
        $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, $tableCreate);
        if ($queryResult === TRUE) {
            print "<br /><br />Table Created";
            $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Custom_Rates (TableName) VALUES ('rates_{$tablename}');");
            $rows = array(
                    array('weight' => 1000, 'cbm_min' => 0.1, 'cbm_max' => 2.3 ),
                    array('weight' => 1500, 'cbm_min' => 2.31, 'cbm_max' => 3.5 ),
                    array('weight' => 2000, 'cbm_min' => 3.51, 'cbm_max' => 4.6 ),
                    array('weight' => 2500, 'cbm_min' => 4.61, 'cbm_max' => 5.75 ),
                    array('weight' => 3000, 'cbm_min' => 5.75, 'cbm_max' => 6.9 ));
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $value = $mins[$i];
                if (empty($value)) {
                    $value = 0;
                }
                $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO rates_{$tablename} (Weight, CBMMin, CBMMax, Min) VALUES (".$row['weight'].",".$row['cbm_min'].",".$row['cbm_max'].",".$value.");");
                if ($queryResult === TRUE){

                }else{
                    print "<br /><br />No Row created. Check " . mysqli_error($con);
                }
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            print "<br /><br />No TABLE created. Check " . mysqli_error($con);
        }

    }
```

If this doesn’t make any sense do say and I will try to draw up some images etc.
I am really just asking if I am going the right way about this, or if it is even possible/a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.button').click( 
     ('.table').html('echo the table HTML here');
       );
 });
```

In your HTML, add a `div` that is empty and give it a class of `.table` as shown in the above code.